Visual Studio takes one-before-last commit for rebase
I have a Visual Studio 2022 solution stored on Azure. It has two branches: "master" and "add_combobox". Latter (my work) has three simple linear commits. Say "one", "two", "three" - all pushed to Azure source repository. Now I want to rebase "add_combobox" onto "master". But Visual Studio takes commit "two" for rebasing, not commit "three". What am I doing wrong?

All this would be much clearer with a git log --oneline --graph master add_combobox output.

@RomainValeri thanks, trying to figure that. I was wrong tho - it took the first commit of "add_combobox" branch (i.e. "one")
